# Calculate translateZ for CSS Transform

Tags: css, safari, transform, clipping

I've run into an issue when using the transform property.

I have 1 simple DIV the fills the screen, and another DIV that sits on top of it.

I'm applying the following transform to the DIV on top:

'transform':'rotateX(Xdeg) rotateY(Ydeg)';
I'm also using preserve-3d

This works perfectly in all browsers except Safari. From what I've read, Safari is the only one that actually gets this correct, and clips the top DIV which the transform is being applied to. The other browsers don't clip the DIV. Basically, when the DIV is rotated, it's going inside/behind the bottom layer DIV.

So, I'm assuming that I need to use translateZ to pull the top DIV forward?

My question is, how would I go about calculating how much I need to translate the div forward along the Z axis, or getting this to work in Safari? The rotate X and Y will be variables, so users might be able to rotate the element along either the X, Y, both or none at all.

Any help on this would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are your X and Y values always positive ?

In this case,

```
transform-origin 0% 0%
```

should do the trick (making the rotation center be the point that will be the lower in the result)

if not, you only need a little logic:

if your X angle is positive, x origin is 0%, else x origin is 100%

if your Y angle is positive, y origin is 0%, else y origin is 100%

and then, apply

```
transform-origin x-origin y-origin
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem without a jsFiddle. You could use a function like `element.getBoundingClientRect()`. This will give you the current coordinates of the second transformed div. If you compare these with the coordinates of the first div you should find the needed translateZ. You need to compare all 4 corners of the transformed div. A negative DELTA means that that corner is intersecting the first div.